# Java split if it find text after command

Tags: java, if-statement, split

I am trying from hours how to do this so I will ask here for help. 
I run a IRC bot and trying to do something, when user is sending command to the bot it needs to see if it can spit the input from the user if there is one.

Example: !help lag 2 3; 
The code works for this just fine but if the user only send

Example: !help;
Its crashing with `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`

Here is the code for that part:

```
String command = str.split("!")[1];
command = command.split("\\s+", 2)[0];
String username_fix = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8").replace("_", "%20");
String combined = "";
String fix = str.split(command)[1];
fix = fix.trim();
String arrayString[] = fix.split("\\s+");
for (int j = 0; j < arrayString.length; j++) {
combined += arrayString[j] + "|";
}
```

Error is coming from `String fix = str.split(command)[1];`

This did the job done `if (str.split(command).length > 1)` by msrd0.

But and rorschach's answer is the same so i will mark this as solved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: debugger might help here

Comment: I try every possible way i can think of to do the check for this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to automatically get the second element of the `str.split(command)` array. Do the split first and then **check** if there is a second element there.

```
//no
String fix = str.split(command)[1];

//yes
String[] something = str.split(command);

if(something.length > 1) {
    //rest of your logic
}
```

Comment: I try doing something like this `if (str.split(command)[1].length() > 1 && !str.split(command)[1].isEmpty()) ` but no luck.. or I am doing it wrong.

Comment: @RandomGuy did you try `if (str.split(command).lenght > 1) ...`?

Comment: Thanks msrd0... that did t he job I guess i was doing [1] the part wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
String fix = str.split(command)[0];
```

Changing this line of code makes it work fine. You were trying to access a location in array (in your case [1]) which was out of max length ([0]).